# How to get currecnt AVFrame sequential number after av_seek_frame?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am new in decoder and FFmpeg. What I need is to implement the logic that can read frames with some step (ex:20), in other words, I have a file and I need to read frames 0, 20, 40, 60...

what I do is

```
AVFrame * m_pAVFrame = nullptr;
int firstFrameIdx = 0;

while(true)
{

if(firstFrameIdx > 0)
{
int64_t seekTarget = FrameToPts(m_pAVStream, firstFrameIdx);
nRet = av_seek_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_streamIdx, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
}

nRet = av_read_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_pAVPkt);
ret = avcodec_send_packet(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVPkt);
ret = avcodec_receive_frame(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVFrame);

firstFrameIdx+=20;
}
```

But problem is that `av_seek_frame` moves the pointer to the Iframe, lets say the video file has keyframes each 15(of course it could be a different number) like 0, 15, 30... So it means that if I try to seek to frame 20 actually I get to frame 15.

I see that `AVFrame` has a property `coded_picture_number` that could be useful in my case, I tried to put these returned values to the vector and I see that these values irrelevant

[image]

what I expected to see there is `0, 15, 30, 45...`

It'll be useful if I for example can make a seek then get a frame to ask the order number (ex:15) then I can understand that Iframe is 15 and in order to reach frame 20 I need to read and skip 5 frames so as a result, I get to frame 20, but as you see above after the seek I ask the order number and get weird values like `0, 2, 1, 3...` there is nothing to do with it...

I feel like there is some basic knowledge that I miss, could someone explain how to make a seek logic and get to the right frame?

**UPDATE**

Init logic

```
bool FFmpegDecoder::Init(unsigned char const * pData, int dataSize, int reqId, bool bUseHWAccel, FFmpegDecoderCallback * pCB)
{
    Deinit();

    // From memory:
    if (pData == nullptr || dataSize == 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::Init FAILED: neither filename nor memory data were given !\n");
        return false;
    }
    m_pIoCtx = std::make_shared<AVIOContextMem>(pData, dataSize);

    if (m_pIoCtx->IsValid() == false)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::Init FAILED: m_pIoCtx is nullptr !\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_reqId = reqId;
    m_bUseHWAccel = bUseHWAccel;
    m_pCB = pCB;
    m_pData = pData;
    m_dataSize = dataSize;

    m_bRequestedAbort = false;

    m_pAVPkt = av_packet_alloc();
    av_init_packet(m_pAVPkt);

    m_pAVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    m_pAVFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

    if (m_bUseHWAccel)
    {
        m_pSwAVFrameForHw = av_frame_alloc();
    }

    m_pAVFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    m_pIoCtx->initAVFormatContext(m_pAVFormatCtx);

    if (avformat_open_input(&m_pAVFormatCtx, "", nullptr, nullptr) != 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avformat_open_input\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(m_pAVFormatCtx, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return false;
    }


    //av_dump_format(ctx_format, 0, "", false);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_pAVFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (m_pAVFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            m_streamIdx = i;
            m_pAVStream = m_pAVFormatCtx->streams[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (m_pAVStream == nullptr)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: failed to find video stream\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pAVCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_pAVStream->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (!m_pAVCodec)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_find_decoder\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pAVCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_pAVCodec);
    if (!m_pAVCodecCtx)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_alloc_context3\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVStream->codecpar) < 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_parameters_to_context\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (m_bUseHWAccel)
    {
        AVHWDeviceType hwDevType = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2;
        g_hwPixFormat = find_fmt_by_hw_type(hwDevType);
        m_pAVCodecCtx->get_format = get_hw_format;
        av_opt_set_int(m_pAVCodecCtx, "refcounted_frames", 1, 0);
        if (av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&m_pBufferRefForHw, hwDevType, NULL, NULL, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in av_hwdevice_ctx_create\n");
            return false;
        }
        m_pAVCodecCtx->hw_device_ctx = av_buffer_ref(m_pBufferRefForHw);
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVCodec, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_open2\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pAVFrameRGB->format = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;
    m_pAVFrameRGB->width = m_pAVCodecCtx->width;
    m_pAVFrameRGB->height = m_pAVCodecCtx->height;
    if (av_frame_get_buffer(m_pAVFrameRGB, 32) != 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in av_frame_get_buffer\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_streamRotationDegrees = GetAVStreamRotation(m_pAVStream);
    m_estimatedFramesCount = 0;
    assert(m_pAVFormatCtx->nb_streams > 0);
    if (m_pAVFormatCtx->nb_streams > 0)
    {
        m_estimatedFramesCount = m_pAVFormatCtx->streams[0]->nb_frames;
    }

    //InitConvertColorSpace
    // Init converter from YUV420p to BGR:
    if (m_bUseHWAccel)
    {
        m_pSwsCtxConvertImg = sws_getContext(m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        m_pSwsCtxConvertImg = sws_getContext(m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, m_pAVCodecCtx->pix_fmt, m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (!m_pSwsCtxConvertImg)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in sws_getContext\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_bInitOK = true;
    return true;
}
```

Decoding logic with last changes

```
void FFmpegDecoder::DecodeWithStep(int step)
{
    step = 20;
    int currentFramePos = 0;
    int number_of_errors = 0;
    const int MAX_ERROR_NUM = 10;

    while (true)
    {
        if (step > 0)
        {
            int seekPos = currentFramePos + step;
            int64_t seekTarget = FrameToPts(m_pAVStream, seekPos);

            if (av_seek_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_streamIdx, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME) < 0)
            {
                number_of_errors++;
            }
            else
            {
                currentFramePos = seekPos;
                m_is_seeked = true;
            }
        }

        if (av_read_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_pAVPkt) == 0)
        {
            if (m_pAVPkt->stream_index == m_streamIdx) //to make sure that I dont get packets from other streams
            {
                if (m_is_seeked)
                {
                    avcodec_flush_buffers(m_pAVCodecCtx);
                    m_is_seeked = false;
                }

                if (avcodec_send_packet(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVPkt) == 0)
                {
                    printf("----- BATCH\n");

                    while (avcodec_receive_frame(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVFrame) == 0)
                    {
                        ProcessFrame(m_pAVFrame);
                        av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
                        currentFramePos++;
                        printf("----- cur position (%d) \n", currentFramePos);
                    }
                }

                av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            number_of_errors++;
        }

        if (number_of_errors == MAX_ERROR_NUM)
        {
            printf("EXIT\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Init logic

```
bool FFmpegDecoder::Init(unsigned char const * pData, int dataSize, int reqId, bool bUseHWAccel, FFmpegDecoderCallback * pCB)
{
    Deinit();

    // From memory:
    if (pData == nullptr || dataSize == 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::Init FAILED: neither filename nor memory data were given !\n");
        return false;
    }
    m_pIoCtx = std::make_shared<AVIOContextMem>(pData, dataSize);

    if (m_pIoCtx->IsValid() == false)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::Init FAILED: m_pIoCtx is nullptr !\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_reqId = reqId;
    m_bUseHWAccel = bUseHWAccel;
    m_pCB = pCB;
    m_pData = pData;
    m_dataSize = dataSize;

    m_bRequestedAbort = false;

    m_pAVPkt = av_packet_alloc();
    av_init_packet(m_pAVPkt);

    m_pAVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    m_pAVFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

    if (m_bUseHWAccel)
    {
        m_pSwAVFrameForHw = av_frame_alloc();
    }

    m_pAVFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    m_pIoCtx->initAVFormatContext(m_pAVFormatCtx);

    if (avformat_open_input(&m_pAVFormatCtx, "", nullptr, nullptr) != 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avformat_open_input\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(m_pAVFormatCtx, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return false;
    }


    //av_dump_format(ctx_format, 0, "", false);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_pAVFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (m_pAVFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            m_streamIdx = i;
            m_pAVStream = m_pAVFormatCtx->streams[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (m_pAVStream == nullptr)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: failed to find video stream\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pAVCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_pAVStream->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (!m_pAVCodec)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_find_decoder\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pAVCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_pAVCodec);
    if (!m_pAVCodecCtx)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_alloc_context3\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVStream->codecpar) < 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_parameters_to_context\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (m_bUseHWAccel)
    {
        AVHWDeviceType hwDevType = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2;
        g_hwPixFormat = find_fmt_by_hw_type(hwDevType);
        m_pAVCodecCtx->get_format = get_hw_format;
        av_opt_set_int(m_pAVCodecCtx, "refcounted_frames", 1, 0);
        if (av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&m_pBufferRefForHw, hwDevType, NULL, NULL, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in av_hwdevice_ctx_create\n");
            return false;
        }
        m_pAVCodecCtx->hw_device_ctx = av_buffer_ref(m_pBufferRefForHw);
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVCodec, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in avcodec_open2\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pAVFrameRGB->format = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;
    m_pAVFrameRGB->width = m_pAVCodecCtx->width;
    m_pAVFrameRGB->height = m_pAVCodecCtx->height;
    if (av_frame_get_buffer(m_pAVFrameRGB, 32) != 0)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in av_frame_get_buffer\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_streamRotationDegrees = GetAVStreamRotation(m_pAVStream);
    m_estimatedFramesCount = 0;
    assert(m_pAVFormatCtx->nb_streams > 0);
    if (m_pAVFormatCtx->nb_streams > 0)
    {
        m_estimatedFramesCount = m_pAVFormatCtx->streams[0]->nb_frames;
    }

    //InitConvertColorSpace
    // Init converter from YUV420p to BGR:
    if (m_bUseHWAccel)
    {
        m_pSwsCtxConvertImg = sws_getContext(m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        m_pSwsCtxConvertImg = sws_getContext(m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, m_pAVCodecCtx->pix_fmt, m_pAVCodecCtx->width, m_pAVCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (!m_pSwsCtxConvertImg)
    {
        printf("FFmpegDecoder::InitFFmpeg: error in sws_getContext\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_bInitOK = true;
    return true;
}
```

```
void FFmpegDecoder::DecodeWithStep(int step)
{
    step = 20;
    int currentFramePos = 0;
    int number_of_errors = 0;
    const int MAX_ERROR_NUM = 10;
    int seekPos = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (step > 1)
        {
            seekPos = currentFramePos + step;
            int64_t seekTarget = FrameToPts(m_pAVStream, seekPos);

            if (av_seek_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_streamIdx, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME) < 0)
            {
                number_of_errors++;
            }
            else
            {
                m_is_seeked = true;
            }
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (av_read_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_pAVPkt) == 0)
            {
                if (m_pAVPkt->stream_index == m_streamIdx) //to make sure that I dont get packets from other streams
                {
                    if (m_is_seeked)
                    {
                        avcodec_flush_buffers(m_pAVCodecCtx);
                        m_is_seeked = false;
                    }

                    if (avcodec_send_packet(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVPkt) == 0)
                    {
                        int ret = 0;
                        while (ret >= 0)
                        {
                            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(m_pAVCodecCtx, m_pAVFrame);

                            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                            {
                                av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
                                break;
                            }

                            currentFramePos = m_pAVFrame->display_picture_number; //In order to get position of currect frame (seek move poiter to the key frame)

                            if (currentFramePos < seekPos) //Some frames need to be skiped in order to reach needed frame
                            {
                                printf("----- SKIP : cur position (%d) \n", currentFramePos);
                                av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
                                continue;
                            }

                            ProcessFrame(m_pAVFrame); //needed frame was processed
                            av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
                            printf("----- cur position (%d) \n", currentFramePos);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt);
                }
                else
                {
                    av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt); //we got a frame from the wrong stream
                }
            }
            else
            {
                number_of_errors++;
            }

            if (number_of_errors == MAX_ERROR_NUM)
            {
                printf("EXIT1\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (number_of_errors == MAX_ERROR_NUM)
        {
            printf("EXIT2\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
int64_t FrameToPts(AVStream* pavStream, int frame)
{
    return (int64_t(frame) * pavStream->r_frame_rate.den *  pavStream->time_base.den) /
        (int64_t(pavStream->r_frame_rate.num) * pavStream->time_base.num);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seek 'accurate' to a specific frame... so you seek to the frame that you want with backwards flag to ensure you get the frame or a previous one. If the case is a previous one you decode until you get the actual requested frame.

There are two important steps that I can see that you're missing:-

1. After each av_seek_frame (demux) and before the next avcodec_send_packet (decode) you need to flush the decoder with avcodec_flush_buffers
2. After each avcodec_send_packet (decode) you need to receive all frames (can be more than one) with avcodec_receive_frame eg:-

```
while (avcodec_receive_frame(...) == 0) { process frame here }
```

### Solution 1 (Without Seek - Small steps or for unknown fps and ensures accuracy)

Let's start with step = 1 to do simple demuxing and what we get

```
public void Aleksey()
{
    AVPacket* m_pAVPkt  = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame*  m_pAVFrame= av_frame_alloc();
    int ret;
    int step = 1;
    int curFrameNumber = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        ret = av_read_frame(demuxer.FormatContext, m_pAVPkt);
        if (m_pAVPkt->stream_index != 0) { av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt); continue; }

        ret = avcodec_send_packet(codecCtx, m_pAVPkt);
        av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt);

        while (true)
        {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codecCtx, m_pAVFrame);
            if (ret != 0) { av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame); break; }

            curFrameNumber++;

            if (curFrameNumber % step == 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"[pts: {m_pAVFrame->pts}] [time: {Utils.TicksToTime((long)(m_pAVFrame->pts * demuxer.VideoStreams[0].Timebase))}] [displaynumber: {m_pAVFrame->display_picture_number}] [codednumber: {m_pAVFrame->coded_picture_number}]");

            av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Output (we see the proper pts/cur frame time but we don't get the frame number with display_picture_number/coded_picture_number). Seems that you can use **m_pAVCodecCtx->frame_number** for this though but I bet it will be reset on each av_seek_frame and then avcodec_flush_buffers.

```
[pts: 0] [time: 00:00:00:000] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 0] [framenumber: 1]
[pts: 42] [time: 00:00:00:042] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 3] [framenumber: 2]
[pts: 83] [time: 00:00:00:083] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 2] [framenumber: 3]
[pts: 125] [time: 00:00:00:125] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 4] [framenumber: 4]
[pts: 167] [time: 00:00:00:167] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 1] [framenumber: 5]
[pts: 209] [time: 00:00:00:209] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 7] [framenumber: 6]
[pts: 250] [time: 00:00:00:250] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 6] [framenumber: 7]
[pts: 292] [time: 00:00:00:292] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 8] [framenumber: 8]
[pts: 334] [time: 00:00:00:334] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 5] [framenumber: 9]
[pts: 375] [time: 00:00:00:375] [displaynumber: 0] [codednumber: 11] [framenumber: 10]
```

This code ensures that you will go exactly X step frames, however it doesn't use seek at all which is bad for performance. if your seek step is small it's fine but if you want to use large steps then we can go with the seek included.

### Solution 2 (With Seek - Better performance)

```
AVFormatContext*m_pAVFormatCtx;
AVCodecContext* m_pAVCodecCtx;
AVStream*       pavStream;
AVPacket*       m_pAVPkt;
AVFrame*        m_pAVFrame;
int             m_streamIdx;
long            startTime;
double          avgFrameDuration;
double          m_streamTimebase;

public void Prepare()
{
    // Using your variable names (mapped with mine)
    m_pAVFormatCtx  = demuxer.FormatContext;
    m_pAVCodecCtx   = codecCtx;
    pavStream       = demuxer.VideoStreams[0].AVStream;
    m_streamIdx     = pavStream->index;

    m_streamTimebase= av_q2d(pavStream->time_base) * 1000.0 * 10000.0; // Convert timebase to ticks so we can easily convert stream's timestamps to ticks
    startTime       = pavStream->start_time != AV_NOPTS_VALUE ? (long)(pavStream->start_time * m_streamTimebase) : 0; // We will need this when we seek (adding it to seek timestamp)
    avgFrameDuration= 10000000 / av_q2d(pavStream->avg_frame_rate); // eg. 1 sec / 25 fps = 400.000 ticks (40ms)

    // Prepare packet/frame for demux/decode
    m_pAVPkt        = av_packet_alloc();
    m_pAVFrame      = av_frame_alloc();
}

public void GetFrame(int index) // Zero-based frame index
{
    int ret;
    long frameTimestamp = (long) (index * avgFrameDuration); // Calculation of FrameX timestamp (based on fps/avgFrameDuration)
    Console.WriteLine($"Searching for {Utils.TicksToTime(frameTimestamp)}");

    // Seeking at frameTimestamp or previous I/Key frame and flushing codec
    ret = av_seek_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, -1, (startTime + frameTimestamp) / 10, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME | AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD);
    avcodec_flush_buffers(m_pAVCodecCtx);
    if (ret < 0) return; // handle seek error

    while (true)
    {
        // Demux Packet
        ret = av_read_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, m_pAVPkt);
        if (ret != 0) break; // handle EOF/error
        if (m_pAVPkt->stream_index != m_streamIdx) { av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt); continue; } // Exclude other streams

        // Send Packet for decoding
        ret = avcodec_send_packet(codecCtx, m_pAVPkt);
        av_packet_unref(m_pAVPkt);
        if (ret != 0) break; // handle EOF/error

        while (true)
        {
            // Receive all available frames for the decoder
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codecCtx, m_pAVFrame);
            if (ret != 0) { av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame); break; }

            // Get frame pts (prefer best_effort_timestamp)
            long curPts = m_pAVFrame->best_effort_timestamp == AV_NOPTS_VALUE ? m_pAVFrame->pts : m_pAVFrame->best_effort_timestamp;
            if (curPts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE) { { av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame); continue; } }

            // Skip frames before our actual requested frame
            Console.WriteLine($"[Skip] [pts: {curPts}] [time: {Utils.TicksToTime((long)(curPts * m_streamTimebase))}]");
            if ((long)(curPts * m_streamTimebase) / 10000 < frameTimestamp / 10000) { av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame); continue; }

            Console.WriteLine($"[Found] [pts: {curPts}] [time: {Utils.TicksToTime((long)(curPts * m_streamTimebase))}]");
            av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Testing with the following code

```
Prepare();
GetFrame(100);
GetFrame(200);
GetFrame(300);
GetFrame(100);
```

Gives the output

```
Searching for 00:00:04:129
[Skip] [pts: 4004] [time: 00:00:04:004]
[Skip] [pts: 4046] [time: 00:00:04:046]
[Skip] [pts: 4087] [time: 00:00:04:087]
[Skip] [pts: 4129] [time: 00:00:04:129]
[Found] [pts: 4129] [time: 00:00:04:129]
Searching for 00:00:08:299
[Skip] [pts: 8008] [time: 00:00:08:008]
[Skip] [pts: 8050] [time: 00:00:08:050]
[Skip] [pts: 8091] [time: 00:00:08:091]
[Skip] [pts: 8133] [time: 00:00:08:133]
[Skip] [pts: 8175] [time: 00:00:08:175]
[Skip] [pts: 8217] [time: 00:00:08:217]
[Skip] [pts: 8258] [time: 00:00:08:258]
[Skip] [pts: 8300] [time: 00:00:08:300]
[Found] [pts: 8300] [time: 00:00:08:300]
Searching for 00:00:12:470
[Skip] [pts: 12012] [time: 00:00:12:012]
[Skip] [pts: 12054] [time: 00:00:12:054]
[Skip] [pts: 12095] [time: 00:00:12:095]
[Skip] [pts: 12137] [time: 00:00:12:137]
[Skip] [pts: 12179] [time: 00:00:12:179]
[Skip] [pts: 12221] [time: 00:00:12:221]
[Skip] [pts: 12262] [time: 00:00:12:262]
[Skip] [pts: 12304] [time: 00:00:12:304]
[Skip] [pts: 12346] [time: 00:00:12:346]
[Skip] [pts: 12387] [time: 00:00:12:387]
[Skip] [pts: 12429] [time: 00:00:12:429]
[Skip] [pts: 12471] [time: 00:00:12:471]
[Found] [pts: 12471] [time: 00:00:12:471]
Searching for 00:00:04:129
[Skip] [pts: 4004] [time: 00:00:04:004]
[Skip] [pts: 4046] [time: 00:00:04:046]
[Skip] [pts: 4087] [time: 00:00:04:087]
[Skip] [pts: 4129] [time: 00:00:04:129]
[Found] [pts: 4129] [time: 00:00:04:129]
```

Note: For the 2nd solutions there is still space for handling better the small steps (frames that are both within the same keyframes). You could validate that by storing the last seek's keyframe and comparing it with the current seek's keyframe. If that's the case you could avoid flushing the codec and re-seeking at the previous frame's position with ANY flag to be an exact seek (to continue the decoder from where it was). The new frame's timestamp must be greater from previous one though.

Comment: Can't see all your code to help you out more. Do you enable only one stream (video stream) to ensure that you dont get packets from other streams (eg. audio) ? Check also my Demuxer code [here](https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf/blob/master/FlyleafLib/MediaFramework/MediaDemuxer/DemuxerBase.cs)

Comment: You need to ensure that you allocate/free or unref your packets/frames as well

Comment: No you still need it, to feed the decoder properly so it will be able to decode the next frame. I will try to produce some c# code for your question. Does FrameToPts works properly, can you publish it as well?

Comment: OK we have some problems here. You cannot trust display_picture_number it will not be set always. You can't trust fps can be dynamic, might as workaround you would use avg frame rate. And one important question ... Do you want the step to be static number and small one?

Comment: You can't trust coded_picture_number either, or you can use it in the way that you want. it is the order of encoding not the actual frame order. You should focus only on timestamps

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know what you think

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko after our detailed discussion I've added a 2nd solution for better performance. I will use it as well for my Flyleaf library for fast step forwards/backwards ;)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko One more update to fix the 1 frame distance accuracy bug