# FFMPEG Implement RTSP Client, high speed playback

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp-client

I am writing software to play videos that have been recorded from NVR. I have completed most of the work, but there is one more feature that allows the user to change the play speed such as 0.5x, 2x, 4x, 8x ...

I searched the internet all day and still couldn't find any suggestions. Here is my summary code below.

```
auto pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

av_dict_set_int(&opts, "rw_timeout", 5000000, 0);
av_dict_set_int(&opts, "tcp_nodelay", 1, 0);
av_dict_set_int(&opts, "stimeout", 10000000, 0);
av_dict_set(&opts, "user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0", 0);
av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_flags", "prefer_tcp", 0);
av_dict_set_int(&opts, "buffer_size", BUFSIZE, 0);

int err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, fullRtspUri, NULL, &opts);
if(err < 0)
    return;
    
err = avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL);
if (err < 0)
    return;
pFormatCtx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_NONBLOCK;
pFormatCtx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_DISCARD_CORRUPT;
pFormatCtx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_NOBUFFER;       
av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, fullRtspUri, 0);
    
int videoStreamInd = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
{
    AVStream* stream = pFormatCtx->streams[i];
    if (stream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        if (videoStreamInd == -1)
        {
            videoStreamInd = i;
            break;
        }
    }   
}

if (videoStreamInd == -1)
    return; 
auto videoStream = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamInd];

isRunning = true;
while(isRunning)
{
    ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, avPacket);
    if (ret < 0)
        return; 

    if (avPacket->stream_index != videoStreamInd)
        continue;
    
    //Code for render process here............
}
```

I have read through this NVR API documentation and see support for 2x, 4x speed play as below

```
Play in 2× Speed:
PLAY rtsp://10.17.133.46:554/ISAPI/streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20170313T230652Z&endtime=20170314T025706Z RTSP/1.0
CSeq:6
Authorization: Digest username="admin", 
realm="4419b66d2485", 
nonce="a0ecd9b1586ff9461f02f910035d0486", 
uri="rtsp://10.17.133.46:554/ISAPI/streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20170313T230652Z&endtime=20170314T025706Z", 
response="fb986d385a7d839052ec4f0b2b70c631"
Session:2049381566;timeout=60
Scale:2.000
User-Agent:NKPlayer-1.00.00.081112

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Session: 2049381566
Scale: 2.000
RTP-Info: url=trackID=1;seq=1,url=trackID=2;seq=1
Date: Tue, Mar 14 2017 10:57:24 GMT
```

How to play RTSP video with speeds of 0.5x, 2x, 4x ...?
Everyone who can assist me in this case, I am very grateful.

Comment: What is the question? What actually does not work?

Comment: Probably duplicate with this question that we discuss last few days [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397968/how-to-get-currecnt-avframe-siquential-number-after-av-seek-frame/67404457#67404457)

Comment: @micha137: I still haven't figured out how to play RTSP video at 0.5x, 2x, 4x.

Comment: @SuRGeoNix: I thought the seek frame function was not what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the "Code for render process here..." you should have code that figures out the delay between presentation/display time for each frame. Whatever that delay is, half it to play twice as fast, double it to play twice as slow and so on. You say this is playing from an NVR, which indicates the stream is probably local and accessed as a media file on disk? If so, it's the speed of the disk and local network connection to the NVR that will limit your ability to play as fast as you want. With my own ffmpeg player code, reading a media file from a M.2 NVMe disk can easily reach 400-700 fps by removing any delay between frames.