# Add frame number/index to AVFrame object

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I have an application that encodes a video stream coming from a camera in H264 and stores it on the disk. In another part of the application I'm loading this movie and showing it to the user. All of this works except the fact that the unique frame index number that I add when encoding the frames aren't the same as the frame numbers that I get when I decode the file.

this is a snippet of my code when I encode a frame. I use "display_picture_number" to store this unique frame number, is this correct? why is the number not the same?

```
void MovieCodec::createFrame( const MyImage& image, AVFrame* frame )
{
    frame->format = streamPixelFormat;
    frame->width = image.width();
    frame->height = image.height();
    frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P;
    frame->display_picture_number = image.uniqueImageNumber();

    int ret = av_image_alloc( frame->data, frame->linesize, frame->width,  frame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, 1);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    struct SwsContext* sws_ctx = sws_getContext((int)image.width(), (int)image.height(), AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                                (int)image.width(), (int)image.height(), streamPixelFormat,
                                                0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    const uint8_t* rgbData[1] = { (uint8_t* )image.getData() };
    int rgbLineSize[1] = { 3 * (int)image.width() };

    sws_scale(sws_ctx, rgbData, rgbLineSize, 0, image.height(), frame->data, frame->linesize);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you can set the display_picture_number. If I'm not wrong this is set by the ffmpeg only. Additionally, I don't think you can trust it as it will change after flushing the codec. If you want to show a specific frame number just calculate it based on the fps. Check this - might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397968/how-to-get-currecnt-avframe-siquential-number-after-av-seek-frame/67404457#67404457

Comment: So there is no member variable in the AVFrame class that I can store my unique frame number  in?

Answer (score 1):

Check [AVFrame](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html) structure documentation.

1. You cannot set display_picture_number as this is will not be processed by ffmpeg during encoding
2. You could use AVFrame 's [metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#a5bde87fd101f66d6263bb451056dba13) instead to store some "notes"

Comment: thank you, I missed that part of the documentation, but this is probably what I need